# Create tab separated print output from a list of tuples python

Tags: python, list, csv, join, tuples

I have a list of tuples that I want to turn into a tab separated format that I can output to the screen.
I have, for example a list of tuples A.

```
[('1_1248', 1, 1),('1_148', 7, 0),('1_18', 6, 1),('1_10', 2, 1)]
```

My code reads:

```
print "ID", "name" , "name"
print("\t".join( repr(e) for e in output))
```

Which produces:

```
ID   name  name
('1_1248', 1, 1)     ('1_148', 7, 0)    ('1_18', 6, 1)  ('1_10', 2, 1)
```

I want some sort of tab separated output (preferably using one or two lines):

```
ID    name  name
'1_1248'  1  1
'1_148'   7  0
'1_18'    6  1
'1_10'    2  1
```

I know how to do this the "long" way, but is there a short 1/2 liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two lines will do:

```
>>> A = [('1_1248', 1, 1),('1_148', 7, 0),('1_18', 6, 1),('1_10', 2, 1)]
>>> for a in A:
...     print "\t".join([str(i) for i in a])
... 
1_1248  1   1
1_148   7   0
1_18    6   1
1_10    2   1
>>>
```

Comment: Yes...that one works well. Thank you! I was trying something like this: `[("\t".join([str(i) for i in a])) for a in output]`. Could you tell me why this does not work?

Comment: You were almost there:
`print "\n".join([("\t".join([str(i) for i in a])) for a in A])` ;)

Comment: ahh yes haha of course! Thank you. I guess I had been coding too long and missed that!

Answer (score 3):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [('1_1248', 1, 1),('1_148', 7, 0),('1_18', 6, 1),('1_10', 2, 1)]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["ID", "name" , "name"])

df 
       ID  name  name
0  1_1248     1     1
1   1_148     7     0
2    1_18     6     1
3    1_10     2     1

# to save
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried this and it also works well.